# Selenium IDE: Why clickAt does not work here?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

Apparently Selenium IDE is fairly unreliable. For example, the last command in the following script does not have any effect inside the script but if I double click on it separately it opens the file selection dialog. Why?

Another question, how do I provide file selection with a next command?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.gumtree.com/" />
<title>gumtree</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">gumtree</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>https://my.gumtree.com/postad</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//form[@id='frmSyi']/div/div/div/div/nav/ul/li[2]/div/span[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//form[@id='frmSyi']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[10]/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//form[@id='frmSyi']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//form[@id='frmSyi']/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[4]/span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=continueButton</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>link=Add image</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you use static delays, rather than waiting for particular elements to appear before trying to click on them, and use ugly long xpath for which you cannot easily tell if it's even correct, then yes, IDE becomes unreliable.
Try to use "waitForElementPresent" before clicking on it and use better locators.

Comment: IDE has been deprecated for years, and Selenium have been pushing people to switch to WebDriver, for much better control over waits.

Comment: @AndrewRegan where did you see that it was deprecated? AFAIK they simply don't treat it as a serious way to test: "Use this to either create simple scripts or assist in exploratory testing." - says the site

Comment: @KirilS. You're right, it's not strictly deprecated, but everything else in my comment, and yours, applies. If OP has high hopes for reliability then IDE is unlikely to be the tool he needs.

Answer (score 0):

ClickAt is a specialised command for clicking coordinates. So you are using it in a wrong way. You should use regular click, or doubleClick or (in a very special case) clickAt with providing coordinates string.

File uploading is not so straight-forward. You should find an input that contains file name for uploading. Send a file-name to it with type command or javascript. And finally initiate uploading. Like:

```
type  | id=hiddenInputForFileName | /path_to_your_file/your_file.lol
click | id=startUploadingButton
```

That's an example. Your code will depend on the file uploading form design. I hope it will help. If it won't please provide the html of your page and I will post the code for your situation.